# Android studio gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently downloaded the android studio and can't understand a few things.
I don't know gradle, and don't really need it, do I have to use it on android studio?
 how do I create a run configuration without a normal android module?

Comment: Gradle for build your android studio project. Btw you have internet connection, why you not try to search more information in google. There's a lot of tutorial that explain you about 'what is gradle' instead ask in here because this is common question

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is a project automation tool that builds upon the concepts of Apache Ant and Maven.
Android Studio is using Gradle as its build tool.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, `Gradle` is the build system used to compile and package your **Android application**. It handles dependencies, compiles your source code, and generates the `APK` file. While it is possible to create Android projects without using `Gradle`, it is highly recommended to utilize `Gradle` as it simplifies the build process and provides additional features and flexibility.